# How to Make a search field and search results in your cocoa apps like spotlight?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Any ideas?
Thans very much!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to search through your own data, you may be thinking about the NSSearchField control.  Here is a link to the ["Introduction to Search Fields Guide"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/SearchFields/SearchFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000168i) in the Apple documentation; it should put you on the right track.

Comment: @peterHosey You are correct of course, but as you've previously pointed out, the original question is vague as to the actual desired implementation.  I was merely attempting to steer @Luke in the right direction if he had his terminology confused (i.e. perhaps he was searching for spotlight when he intended NSSearchField/NSSearchFieldCell).  The documentation I referenced includes sample code for implementing a SearchField.

Comment: Well, that's the front end, but it doesn't do any actual searching. The extent of its involvement is to give you the search string from which you can create a predicate to pass to Core Data or to an NSArrayController to filter the data.

Comment: (Sorry for the out-of-order—I realized my original comment was in error and it was too late to edit it.)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just integrate with Spotlight instead of creating some sort of alternative?

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/MetadataIntro/MetadataIntro.html

If you're actually trying to search for *other* files, you can use Spotlight for that as well:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/SpotlightQuery/SpotlightQuery.html

Comment: I just want to searched from a array or database

Comment: But I want that the results can changed dynamically responded to the key word typed by the user

Comment: @Luke: You should edit your question to clarify that, because your question as it is currently written implies that you want to replicate Spotlight itself—i.e., searching for files.